# ASP MVC Remote Validation Removing Area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation, remote-validation

I have the following Model:

```
public class UserModel 
{
   [Required]
   public String Name {get; set; }

   [Required]
   public String Surname {get; set; }

   [Required]
   [Remote("ValidateIdNumber", "CustomValidation", "", ErrorMessage = "Invalid ID")]
   public String IDNumber {get; set; }
}
```

I have a create user form that is the Admin area. So it's "/Admin/User/Create".

My "ValidateIdNumber" action is in the root in the controller "CustomValidation"
So to access it you would need to go to "/CustomValidation/ValidateIdNumber"

```
public Boolean ValidateIdNumber(String IDNumber) {
     //Validate ID number and return result.
}
```

The problem is that when the form gets created, the remote validation targets "/Admin/CustomValidation/ValidateIdNumber".

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-remote="Invalid ID" data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.IDNumber" data-val-remote-url="/Admin/CustomValidation/ValidateIdNumber" data-val-required="Please provide a ID Number" id="IDNumber" name="IDNumber" type="text" value="">
```

How can I remove the Area? I've tried making the area parameter in the Remote attribute an empty string("") and null.

any ideas? I want to try and keep my validation in the root and not in areas.

Comment: What happens if you just exclude the 3rd parameter? `[Remote("ValidateIdNumber", "CustomValidation", ErrorMessage  = ...`

Comment: I get the same result

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 3 Remote Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289763/asp-net-mvc-3-remote-validation)

Comment: Yes, I've just has a look at Johns link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom remote attribute , see here:

[ASP.NET MVC 3 Remote Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289763/asp-net-mvc-3-remote-validation)